# Getting timestamp from Objecify entity?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, objectify, optimistic-locking

Is it possible to obtain the [timestamp](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Concepts#Transactions) that is used for optimistic concurrency control from an Objectify entity (or a lower-level part of the Google Datastore infrastructure) and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to obtain the version timestamp by specifying a field like this in your entity POJO:

```
@IgnoreSave long __version__;
```

The version # is found in the `Entity` properties with that key. If you're looking for official documentation, check javadocs (and source code) for `Entity.VERSION_RESERVED_PROPERTY` and `Entities.getVersionProperty(Entity)`

**Why This Works**

When you load a low-level `Entity`, it comes pre-populated with a synthetic property named `__version__`. Simply by adding a field to your Objectify POJO with that name, Objectify will load it out of the `Entity`. Use `@IgnoreSave` so that the value is only loaded, never saved.

Comment: Tx. Am I understanding correctly: the name `__version__` is not prescribed by Objectify, but something that I chose; and I'd have to assign its value e.g. from `Entities.getVersionProperty(ofy().save().toEntity(object)`?

Comment: You don't need to do anything explicit other than declare the field. I have added **Why This Works** to my answer, hope that helps!